# Partial Derivation with the TI-NSpire CX CAS

Tags: ti-nspire

I am trying to perform a partial derivation with the TI-NSPIRE CX CAS. However, a variable is always output as 0 in the result.

Example with the nspire:
d/dx(yx) = 0

But I would expect "y" as a result here.

Wolfram gives the expected result as example.
How do I enter in the calculator that y is considered as a variable?

Comment: Maybe it has to be uppercase?

Comment: I dont know, mine works correctly and im getting "y". Are you sure you didnt set the value of "y" to 0 prior to derivate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that there is no implicit multiplication. Use `x*y` not xy